# Jquery variable to php variable in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/gethamsters",
                data: {
                    x: position.coords.latitude,
                    y: position.coords.longitude
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    hamsters = data;               
                }
            });
        });
    }
    </script>
    @foreach ($hamsters as $hamster)
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <center><div>{{ HTML::image($hamster->foto, $hamster->titel, array( 'width' => 200, 'height' => 200 )) }}</div></center>
          <div class="caption">
            <h3><?php echo substr($hamster->titel, 0, 20); ?></h3>
            <p><?php echo substr($hamster->beschrijving, 0, 50); ?></p>
            <center><p><?php echo '<a href=/hamsterdetails/' . $hamster->id . ' class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Meer
info</a><br /> ';?></p></center>
          </div>
        </div>
       </div>
    @endforeach
```

As you can see I got data from my jquery result and I want it to pass it into the `$hamsters` variable in my php code. How can I do that?

Comment: you can't. php is executed on the server, js in your browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we need to clearify what is happening where lets step back back to the basics here:

1. **the Client** requests `GET /hamsters`
2. **the Server** creates and sends response.
3. **the Client** receives response and parses page and runs any javascript on (or linked by) the document  - and can request additional resources with AJAX.
4. **the Client** `POSTs /gethamsters` with x, y coordinates via AJAX.
5. **the Server** processes `POST /gethamsters` request and returns a response to client.